# Мгновенно закрывающееся окно

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Окно появляется только на 1 секунду при запуске данной программы. Можете подсказать, как избавиться от данной проблемы?

```
import pygame
import random

size = width, height = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.init()


def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for i in range(10000):
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('white'),
                    (random.random() * width,
                     random.random() * height, 1, 1))

running = True
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    draw()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: думаю что у вас проблема с отступами. вынесите `pygame.quit()` с тела цикла

Comment: А на сколько надо?

Comment: если вынести pygame.quit() с цикла то выводится только черное окно(остальной код не выполняется)

Answer (score 2):

вам надо вынести `pygame.quit` за основной цикл, и **добавить обновление экрана**

```
... 
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    draw()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: если вынести pygame.quit() с цикла то выводится только черное окно(остальной код не выполняется)

Comment: прочитайте то что я написал после запятой